# API data to innerHTML results in undefined

Tags: javascript

I am just learning JavaScript and about APIs. There are six names in the array this returns.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

req.onload = function(){
    var resp = req.response;
    var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(resp);
    console.log(parsedResponse);
    
    
    for(item in parsedResponse){
        var newElement = document.createElement("li");
        var name = parsedResponse[item].first_name;
        newElement.innerHTML = name;
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);
    }//end for
}//end onload

req.send();
```

This results in:

- undefined
- undefined
- undefined
- undefined
- undefined
- undefined

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[parsedResponse looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye4Vd.png)

It is not an array of strings. They are objects with several fields. first_name is one of them.

Comment: How does `parsedResponse` look like? If `parsedResponse` is an array of strings ("_six names in the array_") , you should not iterate an array with `for ..in`. Secondly, a string doesn't have `first_name` property, that's why you get `undefined`s.

Comment: It looks like `parsedResponse` is an object. Instead of iterating that object, iterate the `data` property using `forEach` method.

Comment: Thanks Teemu. I did forEach on parsedResponse.data and that worked.

Comment: @user77 Adding elements to the DOM directly doesn't force layout rendering. If you're reading a layout-specific value from the DOM during the loop, the layout will be re-calculated, but the page is still not rendered. Re-calculation and rendering takes place after all the script execution has been finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count it from array.length and equal it to i variable like this

```
req.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

req.onload = function(){
    var resp = req.response, 
        parsedResponse = JSON.parse(resp),
        obj_lenght = parsedResponse.data.length, 
        i;
    
    for(i=0;i<obj_lenght; i++){
        var newElement = document.createElement("li");
        var name = parsedResponse.data[i].first_name;
        newElement.innerHTML = name;
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);
    }//end for
}//end onload

req.send();
```

Comment: This worked as well thanks. In my original attempt I also tried parsedResponse.data[item] instead of parsedResponse[item]. Was the problem mainly with my for in loop and using item as the index? I like this better anyway. Just like Java. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

According to you parse response has a `data` property, which is an array of names.

Also, use `of` instead of `in` to iterate over the items instead over the arrays indexes

Just iterate over this array:

```
for (item of parsedResponse.data) {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");
  var name = parsedResponse[item].first_name;
  newElement.innerHTML = name;
  document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```